How do I reduce \$\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C} + \bar{A}\bar{B}C + A\bar{B}\bar{C} + A\bar{B}C\$ to \$\bar{B}\$?
Can someone explain how the simplified version of this boolean expression is B'?
I got A'B' + AB'.


You are just two steps away... Apply the distributive law in reverse.

Is there a reason why you aren't posting this on the math site? It's a pure math question, nothing electronics-specific.

As gb says, take your step: A'B' + AB'
= B'(A' + A)
... and the next step should be obvious- A' + A = ?

\$\overline B\$ is the common factor for all terms hence, it reduces to this: -
$$\overline B(\overline A \overline C+\overline A C+A \overline C+AC)$$
Then reduce more: -
$$\overline B(\overline A( \overline C+C)+A(\overline C+C) )$$
$$\overline B(\overline A(1)+A(1) )$$
And clearly that equals \$\overline B\$.

thnak you I guess my brain was just a bit foggy at the time
